# Is it possible to checkout to enterprise github repo from non enterprise public repo in github actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to checkout to enterprise github repo from non-enterprise public repo. These are my actions:

```
jobs:
  checkout:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.x]
    steps:
    - name: Checkout private tools
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        repository: enterprose/repo
        token: ${{ secrets.ENTERPRISE_TOKEN }} 
        path: main
```

but as I saw it will clone `https://github.com/enterprose/repo`, but my enterprise account is on a different domain. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be an option to clone a non-GitHub.com repository using the actions/checkout action.

In that case you will need to get back to the good ol' days before actions and clone it yourself:

```
- name: Clone private repo
  run: git clone "https://username:$EXTERNAL_TOKEN@github.company.com/my-org/my-repo" main
  env:
    EXTERNAL_TOKEN : ${{ secrets.EXTERNAL_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: Is it secured to clone an enterprise repo from a public repo Github actions?

Comment: Generally speaking it is secure since you have the access token masked and secured in GitHub secrets and the code you clone will not be seen by other user unless you have additional outputs in your GitHub Actions workflows. Depending on what you do with the code, it still might be obvious what it does. Also users will be able to see the host (github.company.com) and org / repo names. If these are classified you might want to mask them too. Or just set your repository to private.

Also: you should only use private (company) code in a public repository if you are EXPLICITLY allowed to do this!

Comment: Is it possible to clone a public Github.com repo to Enterprise Github using actions/checkout action? I can clone it using the regular `git clone` command but I'm curious if it's possible to do with the checkout action as it seems to fail when I try that. @timmeinerzhagen